# How to change the background color only for the current page?

Tags: color, backgrounds

How can I change the background color only for the current page? I found that I can change the color with `\pagecolor{color}` but that unfortunately changes the color for all pages after this command. Any ideas how to limit this command only to the current page?

Answer (score 67):

You could use the `\afterpage` command from the afterpage package to change the color back.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for auto generating text
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\pagecolor{yellow}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\lipsum[22-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Lev: `\nopagecolor` is only available for pdfTeX and LuaTeX. However, dvips, dvipdfm(x) and XeTeX do not support it. So I don't think it is very good.

Comment: +1 for `afterpage`! (for real now, upvote did not work yesterday?!)

Comment: @Leo Liu: I have found that loading `\usepackage[pagecolor=none]{pagecolor}` and invoking with `\newpagecolor{yellow}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}` works with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: @Leo Liu: Oops! Looks like `xelatex` issued a warning but gave expected results. `xelatex` still appears to be unsupported by the package.

Comment: @chandra: Yes, I wanted to state that with my answer. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 30):

To circumvent the issue of `\nopagecolor` being only available for pdfTeX and LuaTeX, you could use the [pagecolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) package and `\newpagecolor{yellow}` to set the new page color and `\restorepagecolor` to restore the pagecolor to the one it was before `\newpagecolor{yellow}` was used. If that color was `white`, it is `white` again, if it was `none`, it is `none` again, and if it was e.g. `green`, it is `green` again. To make the switch back to the old page colour automatically, `\afterpage` as suggested by frabjous can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for auto generating text
\usepackage{afterpage}% for "\afterpage"
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}% With option pagecolor={somecolor or none}
% you can set a page colour here.
% "none" is the default, but if \nopagecolor is not available, "white" will be used.
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\newpagecolor{yellow}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
\lipsum[22-30]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to just use `\pagecolor{yellow}` followed by `\newpage` followed by another `\pagecolor{white}` (or whatever color you want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for auto generating text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\pagecolor{yellow}
\newpage
\pagecolor{white}
\lipsum[22-30]
\end{document}
```