# change pdf standard background color

Tags: color, backgrounds

How is it possible to change the acrobat's background color when someone opens my pdf?

My pdf is produced by XeTeX (using `hyperref` package).

Take a look of the following picture of two different pdfs. The one on the right (with the "abstract") uses a non-standard background color, while the one on the left doesn't.

**EDIT: My question is NOT about changing the background color of pages. It is about changing the standard background color of acrobat reader when someone opens my document (compare grey on the left to light blue on the right)**

[image]

Comment: `\pagecolor`. See any LaTeX manual.

Comment: @MartinSchröder `\pagecolor` is white in both examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the background color only for the current page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page)

Comment: pdfscreen produces such a background; reading pdfscreen.sty may show you how to do this.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: you didn't get the question. I edited it to be more clear.

Comment: @Thérèse: I'm sorry but I can't figure it out... Nevertheless pdfscreen looks great package, I'll have it in mind

Comment: Sorry, I can’t figure it out either, niels, and I’ve tried because I’d like to disable it.  I suspect it’s defined in the section that begins `\let\@PDFSout@Hook\@empty` but someone who knows more about writing macros than I do would have to look at it.

Answer (score 5):

Given Adobe's appalling record as a proxy for malware, I'd suggest switching your PDF viewer.

Should you decide to do this, and move to [PDF XChange Viewer from Tracker Software,](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer/)
then in the preferences dialogue, on the Customize[sic] UI tab, you can select the background colour you want, with or without a gradient (God forbid!).

Comment: I’m no fan of Adobe’s reader, but I don’t think this is exactly what the questioner asked.  The viewer you recommend seems to allow for setting personal preferences, whereas pdfscreen sets the background color in Adobe’s reader for everyone, despite their personal preferences. I’d still like to understand how this works, in order to disable it or at least choose better colors.

Comment: @Thérèse: Yes, on re-reading I think you're correct. However, as I totally disagree with the concept of trying to change someone else's UI defaults, I'm going to leave this answer here as answering what the question "should have been" :)