# Set color of title page with memoir

Tags: color, memoir

I'm writing a report with memoir and would like to set the color of the title page.  The `pagecolor` package looks promising but I can't figure out how to set the color of only the first of two pages in a twoside report.

As an example, here's a MWE but notice how the first *two* pages are red.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\newpagecolor{red}
\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\newpagecolor{white}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you not say that you did not stick to `titlingpage`? It would be much easier then.

Comment: The accepted solution still works with the `titlingpage` environment. flav's answer used `\maketitle` on its own, but either way, `aftepage` was what I was looking for.  Thanks for your behind-the-scenes solution though. Might come in handy for other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use afterpage package :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\title{Test}
\author{flav}
\begin{document}

 \newpagecolor{gray}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
 \maketitle

 \chapter{First chapter}
 \lipsum[1]

 \end{document}
```

see : [How to change the background color only for the current page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page)

Comment: Great, this works with a few minor edits as proposed.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant portion of `memoir.cls` for the title is

```
\newcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \let\footnote\@mem@titlefootkill
  \ifdim\pagetotal>\z@
    \newpage
  \fi
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
        \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookd
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

As such, `\maketitlehookd` is basically the last thing, which should be  on the first titlepage. A `\clearpage` after this hook should do, but is  not the best solution. If there is more content on the first page, such that the content of the hooks go to the 2nd page, the clearpage should be there, but in this sense, the 2nd page is still a titlepage and should be in the same colour, in my point of view. Patching the end of `\@maketitle` is perhaps the better way.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% Patching the end of `\@maketitle` -- Assume that nothing is on the second page. 
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{\par
\vskip 1.5em}{%
\par
\vskip 1.5em
\clearpage\newpagecolor{white}}{}{}%


\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\newpagecolor{red}
\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\newpagecolor{white}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about the first two pages being red, versus only the true title page.