# Set background color for scrbook \maketitle page

Tags: color, koma-script, backgrounds, scrbook, pagecolor

I am using the `scrbook` document class, and **I just want to set the background color** for the standard title page created through `\maketitle`.

I already tried using the `pagecolor` package [1], but it shows no effect for the `scrbook` class. (Works with `memoir`, though.)

[1] https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240862/222387

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please always add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem without needing a special package for it:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\AddToHook{env/titlepage/begin}{\pagecolor{green}}
\AddToHook{env/titlepage/after}{\nopagecolor}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Or for those, who use an old LaTeX without generic hooks:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{green}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\nopagecolor
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

Both examples have the same result:

[image: making all titlepage environments green]

Comment: Thank you. You provided the correct syntax. The "solution" in the link [1] is posted is erroneous.