# Texlive 2017 and xcolor package

Tags: color, texlive-2016, texlive-2017

I am using the suggestion from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page) to change the background color of a page using the MWE example from frabjous. This works in Texlive 2016, but it gives an error in Texlive 2017:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ...e@color \current@color \ifundefined
                                              {GPT@outputbox}{\csname ne...
l.7 \pagecolor{yellow}
                  \afterpage{\nopagecolor}
```

Does anyone else get this error and is there a fix?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a typo in an update: will be fixed probably by tomorrow. For the present, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\set@page@color{\ifundefined}{\@ifundefined}{}{}
\makeatother
```

after loading `xcolor`.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply and solution.

Comment: Planting bugs for getting rep? `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I have adjourned texlive, the file compiles but it doesn't work

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-blue}{rgb}{0.8,0.85,1}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{light-blue}

ciao    

\newpage

\pagecolor{white}

ciao

\end{document}
```

Comment: Curiously, adding `\usepackage[]{crop}` makes this work successfully. (MacTeX 2017, updated this morning with new `graphics-def`.)

Comment: This would make an entirely good new question: I'll fix it today but still will be useful.

Comment: Temporary fix: `\makeatletter
\edef\GPT@pagecolortrue{\global\unexpanded\expandafter{\GPT@pagecolortrue}}
\edef\GPT@pagecolorfalse{\global\unexpanded\expandafter{\GPT@pagecolorfalse}}
\makeatother
`

Comment: @JosephWright copying pasting from your comment there are invisible characters around the @ which will be problematic to innocents (by the way, it does work but you know that ;-) )

Comment: @jfbu The invisible char business is by-design, unfortunately (it's to do with rendering the site and non-breakable blocks ...). It's inserted by the site 'back end' when rendering the HTML and is not in my code as-posted (so not there if you _edit_ the comment, for example).

Comment: @JosephWright I guessed it was not in your code ;-) although one never knows what kind of smart tricks Bruno could have propagated into it... I see about editing not displaying the invisible characters.