# problems with colorpage and texlive update

Tags: graphics, color

after the updating of texlive it doesn't compile

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{light-blue}{rgb}{0.8,0.85,1}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}

ciao    
\newpage
\pagecolor{white}

ciao
\end{document}
```

Comment: Already reported (and fixed in sources): see linked question for a work-around.

Comment: There was a bug in texlive 2017, if you use this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374891/4736