# Make \hl include linebreaks

Tags: pdftex, highlighting, soul, syntax-highlighting

I am using `soul` package and `\hl` to highlight text in my `Latex`. However, it does not work when there is a linebreak or a new paragraph. I have a whole page to highlight. Is it possible to make `\hl` include the linebreaks? How to do it?

Comment: no, soul can't do that. If you want to do heavy highlighting use lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/cool-text-highlighting-in-latex for some background (pun intended...). And if you indeed want to highlight the full page then you could also change the page color (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page).

Answer (score 0):

`\hl` does not work properly with line breaks in LaTeX. However, there is a workaround to highlight text that spans across multiple lines. You can use the `\colorbox` command from the **xcolor** package to create a colored box around the text. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow}{%
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
    This is some text that spans across multiple lines, and it is being highlighted in yellow using the \textbackslash colorbox command from the xcolor package.
}}

\end{document}
```

This code will highlight the text in a yellow box that spans across multiple lines. You can change the color of the box by replacing "yellow" with any other color name or code.